# Calculating the Poynting vector

Tags: optics

Why is the equation $S=...=\frac{1}{\mu_0 c}E_0^2=\epsilon_0 c E_0^2$ accurate? Shouldn't it be $\epsilon_0 c^2 E_0^2$ instead, since $c=\frac{1}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}$...

Comment: The wave equation is $\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \dots = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \dots$, so $c=(\mu_0 \epsilon_0)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poynting vector is $\mathbf S = \frac1{\mu_0}\mathbf E\times\mathbf B$. For an electromagnetic wave we have the relation $\mathbf E = \mathbf v\times\mathbf B$, where the magnitude of $\mathbf v$ is $c$, the speed of light. So the magnitude of $\mathbf S$ is
$$S = \frac1{\mu_0c}E^2.$$
Now use the fact that $c = 1/\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$ to get
$$S = \epsilon_0cE^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$c^2=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}$